# C++ Создание задачи автозапуска от имени текущего пользователя

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Данный пример создаёт задачу в Планировщике заданий Windows, которая запускает приложение при входе текущего пользователя в систему. Однако `RegisterTaskDefinition` возвращает `E_ACCESS_DENIED`. При запуске от имени администратора задача создаётся успешно. Обязательно ли нужны права администратора для регистрации задач с триггером `TASK_TRIGGER_LOGON` или я что то упускаю? По логике вещей, если задача создаётся от имени текущего пользователя и запускается только при его входе в систему, то зачем тут права администратора?

```
#define CHECK_HR_EXIT(hr) if (FAILED(hr)) goto Exit;

BOOLEAN CreateStartupTask(LPCTSTR lpszAppPath, LPCTSTR lpszTaskName)
{
    BOOLEAN bResult = FALSE;
    ITaskService* pTaskService = NULL;
    ITaskFolder* pRootTaskFolder = NULL;
    ITaskDefinition* pTaskDef = NULL;
    ITaskSettings* pTaskSettings = NULL;
    ITriggerCollection* pTriggers = NULL;
    ITrigger* pTrigger = NULL;
    IActionCollection* pActions = NULL;
    IAction* pAction = NULL;
    IExecAction* pExecAction = NULL;
    IRegisteredTask* pRegisteredTask = NULL;

    CHECK_HR(CoInitialize(NULL));

    TCHAR szWorkingDir[MAX_PATH];
    size_t inx;
    CHECK_HR_EXIT(StringCchCopy(szWorkingDir, MAX_PATH, lpszAppPath));
    inx = wcschr(szWorkingDir, '\\') - szWorkingDir;
    if (inx >= 0) szWorkingDir[inx] = 0;

    CHECK_HR_EXIT(CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(TaskScheduler),
        NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
        __uuidof(ITaskService), (void**)&pTaskService));

    // Establish a connection to the task scheduler on the local computer.
    CHECK_HR_EXIT(pTaskService->Connect(CComVariant(),
        CComVariant(),
        CComVariant(),
        CComVariant()));

    // Create an empty task definition in the root task folder.
    CHECK_HR_EXIT(pTaskService->GetFolder(CComBSTR(L"\\"), &pRootTaskFolder));
    CHECK_HR_EXIT(pTaskService->NewTask(0, &pTaskDef));

    // Set settings for task.
    CHECK_HR_EXIT(pTaskDef->get_Settings(&pTaskSettings));
    CHECK_HR_EXIT(pTaskSettings->put_DisallowStartIfOnBatteries(VARIANT_FALSE));
    CHECK_HR_EXIT(pTaskSettings->put_ExecutionTimeLimit(CComBSTR("PT0S")));
    CHECK_HR_EXIT(pTaskSettings->put_AllowDemandStart(VARIANT_FALSE));
    CHECK_HR_EXIT(pTaskSettings->put_Hidden(VARIANT_TRUE));

    // Create trigger object and configure it so that the task runs when user logs on.
    CHECK_HR_EXIT(pTaskDef->get_Triggers(&pTriggers));
    CHECK_HR_EXIT(pTriggers->Create(TASK_TRIGGER_LOGON, &pTrigger));

    // Create execution action object and configure to run the specified app.

    CHECK_HR_EXIT(pTaskDef->get_Actions(&pActions));
    CHECK_HR_EXIT(pActions->Create(TASK_ACTION_EXEC, &pAction));

    CHECK_HR_EXIT(pAction->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IExecAction), (void**)&pExecAction));
    CHECK_HR_EXIT(pExecAction->put_Path(CComBSTR(lpszAppPath)));
    CHECK_HR_EXIT(pExecAction->put_WorkingDirectory(CComBSTR(szWorkingDir)));

    // Register task. Task will only run given an interactive 
    // logon session for the current user.
    CHECK_HR_EXIT(pRootTaskFolder->RegisterTaskDefinition(CComBSTR(lpszTaskName),
        pTaskDef, TASK_CREATE_OR_UPDATE,
        CComVariant(),
        CComVariant(),
        TASK_LOGON_INTERACTIVE_TOKEN,
        CComVariant(),
        &pRegisteredTask));

    bResult = TRUE;

Exit:
     
    if (pTaskService) pTaskService->Release();
    if (pRootTaskFolder) pRootTaskFolder->Release();
    if (pTaskDef) pTaskDef->Release();
    if (pTaskSettings) pTaskSettings->Release();
    if (pTriggers) pTriggers->Release();
    if (pTrigger) pTrigger->Release();
    if (pActions) pActions->Release();
    if (pAction) pAction->Release();
    if (pExecAction) pExecAction->Release();
    if (pRegisteredTask) pRegisteredTask->Release();

    CoUninitialize();
    return bResult;
}
```

Comment: Раз система требует - значит права админа нужны. Есть разделы ОС, изменения в которые можно вносить только с правами администратора. Изменение загрузки, реестр, управление службами и т.д. "если задача создаётся от имени текущего пользователя и запускается только при его входе в систему, то зачем тут права администратора" - а задача эта вирус-шифровальщик. Ну и пусть она автоматически стартует?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/security-contexts-for-running-tasks#security-for-registering-tasks

Comment: @DmitryK _"Ну и пусть она автоматически стартует?"_ - Есть раздел реестра, отвечающий за автозапуск, в который можно вносить изменения без прав администратора. Как можно прочитать по ссылке от user7860670, проблема возникает, когда пользовать входит в группу Администраторы - требуется указать пароль. Это как раз мой случай.

Comment: если пользователь в админах, добавляйте манифест с соответствующими UAC security